# PowerMockito for private non-static void method is not called

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I want to test my private mocked method which is called everytime whae I start my method to test. The private method should only change the members of the argument list. Below is my configuration

```
MyClass myObject = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        log.info("answer started");
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        if (args[0] != null) {
            //change the first argument
        }
        return null;
    }
}).when(myObject, method(MyClass.class, "myMethod"));
```

the myMethod looks like this:

```
private void myMethod(List<AnotherObject> anotherList){...}
```

The problem is that this configuration is not enough for the mock to be called:

> the log-line does not appear.

I tried to write only name of method and to add arguments like:

```
 when(myObject, "myMethod", myAnotherList);    
 when(myObject, "myMethod", anyList());
 when(myObject, method(MyClass.class, "myMethod")).withArguments(myAnotherList);
 when(myObject, method(MyClass.class, "myMethod")).withArguments(anyList());
```

Some of them contained an error, some of them were not completely called.
Could you help me with configuration?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve], do you have a @PrepareForTest?

Comment: Have you tried to debug a test-run to verify the line gets not called? maybe just other console or deleted after printing - maybe you just ignored/missed/overlooked it?